# Vibrates in Idle

Tags: toyota, rough-idle

I have a 1999 RAV4 with 120,000 that's vibrating at Stops when in Drive, but not when in Neutral. Would it help long term if I used Neutral when stopped?  OR should I start looking for another car?  I'm not a mechanic.  Thanks

Comment: Does it always happen or only after the car is warm?

Comment: It's the engine light on?

Answer (score 2):

This hardly sounds like a problem for which the whole vehicle needs replacement.

The symptoms could be explained by a misfiring cylinder, in which the vibrations are most obvious at idle and with the drivetrain engaged.

Common causes for misfires include ageing spark plugs/wires, absence of spark or improper fuel delivery (usually a clogged fuel injector).

Comment: A flashing check engine light would typically occur if misfires are the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would not put it in neutral every time you stop.  You risk premature wear and tear on the shifting mechanisms.

It depends on what you mean by vibration.  A little (slightly inconsistent) vibration when idling is just fine and is not worth doing anything about.

Answer (score -1):

you need to change your engine seat, I had same issue with my 1999 Rav4.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Great idea. but your answer could use a bit more detail as to why the 'engine seat' is the issue to be more helpful and complete. What does the engine seat do? Where is it located? Why would a bad engine seat cause this problem? Help the OP understand the problem, as well as the solution. Thanks for the contribution!